# Vertically align first div in multiple table heading cells

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I have this which has multiple divs inside a first heading cell and a single div inside a second heading cell. Right now if you run the below code, "123" will be in center(not vertically align with "abc") -

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>
      <div>abc</div>
      <div>xyz</div>
    </th>
    <th>
      <div>123</div>
    </th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want to vertically allign 'abc' and '123'.

Comment: Why put div's inside `<th>` tho thats not pseudo

Answer (score 0):

Change the vertical alignment for the cell with "123"

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>
      <div>abc</div>
      <div>xyz</div>
    </th>
    <th style="vertical-align: top;">
      <div>123</div>
    </th>
  </tr>
</table>
```